# Question about grid and data type conversion

Tags: c

I am making a 12* 12 grid with numbers leading the columns and rows, leftover place placed by '.'.

```
void creatGrid(){
    char theGrid[SizeX][SizeY];
    for(int b = 0; b<SizeY;b++){
            theGrid[0][b] = b + 0;
            for(int i =0;i<SizeX;i++){
                if(b==0){
                    char t = i+0;
                    theGrid[i][b] = t;
                }else if(i==0){
                    char e = b+0;
                    theGrid[i][b] = e;
                }else{
                    theGrid[i][b] = '.';
                }
            }
        }
    for(int i = 0;i<SizeY;i++){
        for(int a =0; a<SizeX;a++){
            printf("%c ",theGrid[a][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I am using a char-type two-dimensional array to create the grid, I convert the int to char by adding 0 behind them, but it is not working as the output is gibberish at the position of int.

Comment: The definition `char t = i+0;` is equal to `char t = i;`. And there's just no need for this `t` variable to begin with, you can assign the value of `i` directly to `theGrid[i][b]`.

Comment: `char theGrid[SizeX][SizeY];` ??? Why do you swap, at the very beginning, the conventional perception of rows and columns? Ordinarily, a grid is defined with 'y' rows, each with 'x' columns.... The two printing loops do seem to follow convention.

Comment: More related to your problem, there is no known encoding where e.g. `1 == '1'`. The integer value `1` is **SOH** (start of header) in ASCII encoding, and it's not printable. Perhaps what you really want is `i + '0'` (instead of `i + 0`)?